# Jenkins, Powershell Plugin and Windows Security update KB5004285

Tags: powershell, jenkins, windows-server-2012-r2

Jenkins pipelines used to work until the server (Microsoft 2012r2) was updated with the latest round of security patches in July.  This update included KB5004285.  The Jenkins Powershell plugin is installed to enable the use of Powershell scripts.  Jenkins now fails to build with the following error:

```
powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& 'C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins5679466554526768892.ps1'"
```

Build step 'Windows PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Looking in above file location, that file doesn't exist.

There are errors in the event log:

```
Faulting application name: powershell.exe, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x545044c0
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.3.9600.20090, time stamp: 0x60e91208
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0002a3c0
Faulting process id: 0xdf4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d7adf031f0eb65
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 702c8464-19e3-11ec-8126-0050568b7931
```

It use to be that the security patch could be uninstalled and this would resolve the issue, although this is no longer the case.  Anti-virus software has also temporarily been disabled to see if that was causing an issue, but that made no difference.

The service account used by Jenkins has admin rights on the server, I can log in as that user, create and run powershell scripts within C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp.  Jenkins and the powershell plugin module are up to date as of 2 weeks ago, at a loss of what to try next, but fear a complete rebuild on to Microsoft Server 2019.

Comment: It sounds like this is a [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins.io/) to be reported there.